# Numerical integration of a function containing nonparametric pdf and CDF

Tags: r, integrate, numerical-integration

I'm trying to integrate the following function: *t * ( ( 1 - F(t) )^( ( 1 - .75* b ) / (.75 * a ) ) ) * f(t)* in a finite interval between the realization of the random variable *X* and its upperbound. F(x) is a CDF while f(x) is a pdf. Both `F(x)` and `f(x)` are nonparametrically defined (using the `np` package) as unconditional CDF and pdf respectively.  I'm using `integrate` from the `stats` library to perform the numerical integration. I need to perform this for each value in the vector `x`.

```
# create the values for x
n <- 10
s <- 100
x <- rlnorm(c(n), meanlog = 5, sdlog = 1)
for(i in 2:s){
x <-c(x, rlnorm(c(n), meanlog = 5, sdlog = 1))
}
trim <- 0.01
a <- .2
b <- .3

# Compute pdf and CDF
bw_pdf <- npudensbw(dat = x, bwmethod = 'normal-reference', 
                   trim = trim)
bw_CDF <- npudistbw(dat = x, bwmethod = 'normal-reference', 
                   trim = trim)

f1 <- npudens(bws=bw_pdf)
F1 <- npudist(bws=bw_CDF)


X <- data.frame(x, F1$dist, f1$dens, row.names=NULL)
integ1 <- function(t){
i <- which.min((X$x - t)>=0)
cdf <- X$F1.dist[i]
pdf <- X$f1.dens[i]
vi <- X$x[i]
vector1 <- vi * ( ( 1 - cdf )^( ( 1 - .75* b ) / (.75 * a ) ) ) * pdf
return( vector1 )
}

y <- c()
for(i in 1:length( x ) ){
vv <-x[i]
Z <- integrate( integ1(vv),lower = vv, upper = max(x) )
y <- rbind(y,Z)
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in match.fun(f) : 'integ1(vv)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

Finally, I'm not sure whether the `which` formula is correct. I'm using it to find the value in the vector *X* which is just larger than the `vv` to perform the integration only in the interior from `vv` and the upperbound of `X`.

Thank you for your help.

---

**Edit**: using the `quadgk` command in the `Pracma` library as follows the integration works:

```
integ1 <- function(t){
   i <- which.min((X$x - t)>=0)
   cdf1 <- X$F1.dist[i]
   pdf1 <- X$f1.dens[i]
   vi1 <- X$x[i]
   vector1 <- t * ( ( 1 - cdf )^( ( 1 - .75* b ) / (.75 * a ) ) ) * pdf
   return( vector1 )
}

for(i in 1:length( x ) ){
  vv <-x[i]
  Z <- quadgk( integ1, vv, max(x) )
}
```

Still I'm not sure whether the `which` formula makes sense, which is my **main** issue.

Comment: `trim` is undefined in your example

Comment: sorry, you can disregard trim. In my code it is set at 0.01, but you can delete it.

Comment: Make sure that your example really works.. `v1`, `a`, `b` remain undefined too.

Comment: Yes, sorry again. It's just that I tried to simplify the notation. `a` and `b` are parameters (.2 and .3) and `v1` is actually `X`